# zip -urj command fails in jenkins pipeline shell script

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have jenkins job that add the files to existing zip file

Below is the command that I am using:

```
zip -urj ./$zipFileName ./template/CM/provision/start.sh
```

This runs sometimes and sometimes it fails
Here is the log i get on failure:

```
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

Comment: How about log from shell itself? Maybe you should run `zip` in verbose mode and catch more information about error. Also, is `-r` option needed at all?

Comment: the job is running on server, and i dont have access to it, so it is not possible to see the logs

Comment: Jenkins is grabbing console output from running tasks, you could add `-v` (verbose) switch to `zip` command and hopefully more information will show up.

Comment: when I used `-v` options, I got this extra line on console `zip diagnostic: start.sh up to date`. This is my command `zip -vurj ./$zipFileName ./template/CM/provision/start.sh`

Comment: Maybe `zip` commands returns non-zero exit code. You may display exit status by adding below `zip` like sth like: `echo $?` and confront returned value with [zip man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zip).

Comment: @Tupteq using `echo $?` worked, it printed out the error code as `12`. and I had `set -e` at start of my script which was causing the build to fail